# Coinbase API authentication always invalid signature with Java

Tags: java, sha256, coinbase-api

I've been trying to authenticate myself at the Coinbase API with Java. I've been looking for my mistake for a few days now but can't find it. I always receive an Invalid Signature mistake. My method for creating a signature looks like this:

```
public static String createSignature(String secret, String time, String method,String uri, String body) throws URISyntaxException, JSONException {
    String keyspec = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(secret);
    System.out.println("Keyspec: " + keyspec);
    String prehash = time + method.toUpperCase() + uri + body;
    String sign = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256(prehash.getBytes()));
    System.out.println("Signature: " + sign);
    return sign;
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
String path = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user";
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI(path))
            .headers("CB-ACCESS-KEY","my_access_key","CB-ACCESS-SIGN",createSignature("my_secret_key", path, "GET",currTime,""),"CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP",currTime)
            .GET()
            .build();
```

I also get the current epoch time from the Coinbase API so a difference between the time of my PC and the server shouldn't be the case.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please also provide your error stacktrace

Comment: @retoen the error he's referring too is the coinbase JSON return `{"message": "invalid signature"}`

Comment: CB docs don't explain how to sign very well and it seems to be different between pro and .com.  check these examples and see if it better helps. They don't decode the key and use a hex digest:

https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private HttpHeaders prepareHeaders(String method, String path, String body) throws Exception {
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant());
    String tsSeconds = String.valueOf(timestamp.toInstant().getEpochSecond());

    var message = tsSeconds + method + path + body;
    String signature = encode("HmacSHA256", coinbaseAPISecret, message);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("CB-ACCESS-KEY", coinbaseAPIKey);
    headers.add("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signature);
    headers.add("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", tsSeconds);
    headers.add("CB-VERSION", LocalDate.now().toString());

    return headers;
}

private String encode(String algorithm, String key, String data) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm);
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(secretKeySpec);
    return Hex.encodeHexString(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
}
```